# Are total return indices adjusted for tax?

Tags: index

Just curious about the total return index for stock such as S&P 500 TR, is the index typically adjusted for tax on dividend when accounting for calculation on the total return index?

Comment: I would assume they are not as the taxation would depend on which country you are based.

Comment: @phdstudent Thanks for the help.

Comment: You must carefully read the documentation for the TR index. Some MSCI  indexes for ex. deduct dividend withholding tax in countries where such a withholding is law.

Comment: @noob2 Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the U.S., the convention is not to consider taxes in total return stock indices such as the S&P 500.

The reason why this is traditionally done this way is that much of the buy-side are various kinds of pension funds who don't need to think about taxes.

Someone who does need to think about taxes just has more moving parts to worry about.